# Python Program User Defined Function

Tags: python, syntax, user-defined-functions

```
    def challenge(nums=[],maxes=[]):
    okc=[]
    for el in maxes:
        for le in nums:
            if el>=le:
                okc.append(le)
    print("The final array is:{}".format(okc))


print("Enter the length of first array:")
a=[]
b=[]
n=int(input())
print("Enter the {} elements of the array:".format(n))
for i in range(n):
    z=input()
    a.append(z)
a=list(map(int,a))
print("Enter the length of second array:")
m=int(input())
print("Enter the {} elements of the array:".format(m))
for j in range(m):
    y=input()
    b.append(y)
b=list(map(int,b))
challenge(a,b)
```

The above program is a simple python program which takes in one array and compares the elements with a second array. When I run the Program it shows 'okc' undefined, even though I have defined it. What is the problem?

Comment: Where is the traceback?

Comment: I ran it in Python2 and Python3 with no errors.

Comment: I suspect of indentation problems. If the first print is wrongly indented (outside the function)  you'll get that error because okc is local to the function. Check indentation.